# Can't figure out Shaders for DirectX11?

Tags: c++, windows, directx-11, direct3d11

So, I have no idea how to use shaders. Coding them is easy, but not actually *using them*. MSDN is really useless to me, meaning they have the worst tutorials out there. I am currently reading Frank Luna's Direct3d 11 book, and I am finally to the part where I actually get to draw stuff. Exciting, except for the fact that it **doesn't** work. His BoxDemo - I'm sure worked 3 years ago when the book was made, but now with all of the new DirectX stuff - omitting the DirectX SDK and now using "Windows SDK", FX being deprecated, no more D3DX libraries... So frustrating. I went ahead and downgraded to the DirectX 2010 SDK - just so I can actually use a tutorial. Almost every D3D tutorial out there uses the D3DX libraries.

Anyway... now to my question. Visual Studio has an option to make .hlsl files. But, it also has the ability make .fx files (if you just type .fx at the end of the file name it creates .fx file). 
So, I could use the deprecated .fx way and learn how to use it easily with all of the tutorials teaching it - OR I can learn the *new* HLSL way, and have the hardest, most frustrating time trying to learn it with no tutorials.

I know they both use the HLSL language. But they both are used in the program differently. (CreateEffectFromMemory, CompileFromFile, etc). 
I kind of hope to learn the new way, but if I don't that is fine. Although, I pretty much have an entire program using an .fx file. I'm sure it will work, but I just need help building and utilizing "Effects11.lib".

Sorry for the dragging on post - in fact, I am sure I will not get any replies for a while - if I do get any - due to the length. I am pretty frustrated because learning DirectX has put my programming career on a massive hiatus for the past month, 2 months. Please and thank you for any help

Answer (score 5):

The file extension `.hlsl` vs. `.fx` is arbitrary. It's like the difference between `.cpp` and `cxx`. Historically `.fx` is used for HLSL shaders that included vertex shaders, pixel shaders, and the Effects (FX) techniques/passes, and `.hlsl` is a file that didn't include the Effects (FX) techniques/passes, but is just a convention. There's plenty of both used out there.

What matters is how the file is **compiled**. If you use `fx_5_0`, then it requires the Effects 11 runtime to actually use them. This itself is really nothing special. It effectively just invoke the same compiler for each combination of `compile` statements you provided for the Effects (FX) techniques/passes and bundles it up with some meta-data. In fact, you can often invoke the FXC compiler on a `.fx` file containing techniques/and passes using something like `vs_5_0` or `ps_4_0` and it will compile the appropriate stage-specific shader if you get the parameters just right.

**RE: Effects11**

The main issue with Effects 11 is that it requires the D3DCompile DLL at runtime because it uses that to extract the metadata required to wire up the state and shaders. This D3DCompile DLL is not usable with Windows Store apps in Windows 8.0 and Windows phone 8.0 when you actually *deployed* the app, only when you were *developing* the app. Thus, Effects 11 wasn't usable for those platforms.

This is no longer a technical issue for Windows Store apps for Windows 8.1 or Windows phone 8.1, but the compiler support for `fx_5_0` is still deprecated. It has a few issues that are fixed for the other profiles `vs_5_0`, etc. A such, it's up to you if you want to use it or not as long as you understand it's limitations.

The latest version of Effects 11 is on [CodePlex](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=271568) and I address the limitations there. There are some simple [tutorials](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Effects-Tutorial-Win32-b03b8501) that use it, as well as a few [samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Effects-11-Win32-Samples-cce82a4d). This version of *Effects 11* actually doesn't need the legacy DirectX SDK at all.

**In short, YMMV w.r.t. to Effects 11 but you can still use it for Win32 desktop apps, Windows Store apps for Windows 8.1, Windows phone 8.1 apps, and in theory with Xbox One apps too.**

**RE: D3DX**

I can understand the frustration, but it's a common issue with the book publishing industry and technical books being way behind the ball in terms of changes. DirectX 11 was introduced back in 2008. The transition to the Windows 8 SDK came in 2012 and most developers much less book publishers completed missed it. I have some notes on that book on my [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2014/04/07/book-recommendations.aspx).

For a complete list of 'modern' alternatives, see [Living without D3DX](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/08/21/living-without-d3dx.aspx).

For Win32 desktop apps, you can continue to use the legacy DirectX SDK. The main thing to note is that with the Windows 8.x SDK that comes with VS 2012 and VS 2013, the `include` and `lib` path orders are *reversed* than they were with VS 2010. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx) for details.

**RE: Learning Direct3D 11**

Have you looked at the [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929)?

[Getting Started with Direct3D 11](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2011/07/11/getting-started-with-direct3d-11.aspx)

[Direct3D Feature Levels](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/06/20/direct3d-feature-levels.aspx)

[HLSL, FXC, and D3DCompile](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/05/07/hlsl-fxc-and-d3dcompile.aspx)

As for tutorials and samples, try [DirectX SDK Samples Catalog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/09/20/directx-sdk-samples-catalog.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! Really cleared up some stuff between FX and hlsl stuff.
And that list will probably come in handy - maybe when I move on to Window 10 next year. 
Lastly, I've been having numerous problems time and time again with DirectX. I am not giving up, no. Most certainly not. It just builds up a way bigger challenge for me. I understand what does what and all, but the code is what gets me. 
Thanks again for the post!