# DirectX 11 & Windows SDK: any modern project setup tutorials for Windows 7?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-7, directx-11

Note: I just wanna say at first that I tried literally **everything** I could find about the subject (MSDN, Stack Overflow, D3DCoder, etc.) without any success (after solving one, another error was waiting for me). So I am posting here by pure demotivation (there are similar posts already, yes, but none of them actually helped me out).

Here is how it goes:

A few months ago, I decided to start learning modern OpenGL by pure curiosity, and finally decided to switch to DirectX after reading the downsides of OpenGL (I was also only targeting Windows platform). I think it was one of the worst move I ever made: I heard that OpenGL was lacking of documentation and everything was a mess with third party libraries, but I realized that DirectX was **way worst** than what it seemed to be compared to OpenGL. In fact, trying to code in modern DirectX 11 using Windows 7 and VS2013 is just a pain (especially shaders) and the time it takes to figure it all out is just a time waster. After reading a lot of porting articles on MSDN about alternative libraries, like DirectXTK, DirectXTex, DirectXMesh, Effects11 and DXUT, I still don't know what to do and how to setup a fully working modern project in Windows 7. Specifically, the 5 (/5_0) shader model (deprecated) combined with the new Effects11 library (not deprecated) is the thing that confuse me the most.

By the way, I am currently reading the latest Frank Luna book about the subject ('Introduction to 3D Game Programming with Direct3D 11') and I still can't get his samples working at all (even with DirectX SDK). Also, I don't know if what I am learning is relevant or not since he wrote it before the Windows SDK switch. For your information, the latest error I am trying to solve with his samples (for those who know the book) is a E_NOINTERFACE from D3DX11CreateEffectFromMemory function (at runtime):

[image: E_NOINTERFACE]

```
HR(D3DX11CreateEffectFromMemory(compiledShader->GetBufferPointer(), compiledShader-   >GetBufferSize(), 
    0, md3dDevice, &mFX));

// Done with compiled shader.
ReleaseCOM(compiledShader); -> crash here
```

All that being said, here is what I wanna know:

1. Are there any **clear** step-by-step tutorials on how to setup a modern DirectX 11 project in Windows 7 using VS2013 or it is still in pre-alpha stage (just kidding)?
2. What is actually going on with the shader model, the HLSL compiler, and the .fx files and what should be used (I hear everywhere that it is deprecated but no replacement seems to exist yet)?
3. For those who know the book, any idea on how to build the old DirectX SDK samples without getting this silly runtime error?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`E_NOINTERFACE` is an usual error in that context, so likely there's something wrong with the code around it you are not showing in your question.

You can still use the legacy DirectX SDK with VS 2013, but it takes a slightly different procedure than was used with VS 2010. In `VC++ Directories` set Executable to `$(ExecutablePath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Utilities\bin\x86` or `$(ExecutablePath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Utilities\bin\x64;$(DXSDK_DIR)Utilities\bin\x86`, Include to `$(IncludePath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Include`, and Library to `$(LibraryPath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Lib\x86` or `$(LibraryPath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Lib\x64`. Read [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx) for some other details of doing this. I've also made some notes w.r.t. to that book [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2014/04/07/book-recommendations.aspx).

**You actually don't need the legacy DirectX SDK, but you may find it easier to do that for now using that book.** VS 2013 comes with the Windows 8.1 SDK that has all the OS headers for DirectX 11 along with D3DCompile #47.

You can use the [Direct3D tutorial](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Direct3D-Tutorial-Win32-829979ef) for a simple example of setting up a Win32 desktop app (i.e. one that works on Windows 7) with a device, swapchain, and window. This makes no use of legacy DirectX SDK.

There are some additional [Effects Tutorial Win32 Sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Effects-Tutorial-Win32-b03b8501) you can use as well. Instructions on adding the [Effects 11 library](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=271568) is on the CodePlex wiki under *Documentation / Effects  11 / Adding to a VS solution.*

Your questions about FX vs. not are also covered on the CodePlex: [Is Effects 11 deprecated?](https://fx11.codeplex.com/discussions/450240) and [How do I avoid using fx_5_0?](https://fx11.codeplex.com/discussions/551302). Also on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27326461/cant-figure-out-shaders-for-directx11/27326955#27326955).

Many of the older DirectX SDK samples have been reposted to MSDN Code Gallery and do *not* require the legacy DirectX SDK to build. You should read these posts for the fate of various DirectX SDK things:

[DirectX SDK Samples Catalog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/09/20/directx-sdk-samples-catalog.aspx)

[DirectX SDK Tools Catalog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2014/10/28/directx-sdk-tools-catalog.aspx)

[Living without D3DX](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/08/21/living-without-d3dx.aspx)

[DirectX SDKs of a certain age](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/08/22/directx-sdk-s-of-a-certain-age.aspx)

The story for learning DirectX 11 with Windows Store apps / Windows phone 8.x aps is a lot cleaner, and is well supported by VS templates and MSDN documentation. Win32 desktop apps are of course a completely reasonable option, but you have to distinguish between legacy and modern with a bit of research. You still start with the standard Win32 desktop app project template in VS.

Note: Windows by default only supports OpenGL v1.5 software renderer. You have to install 3rd party ICD to get anything else, and there are no OpenGL VS templates.

Comment: If you are using VS 2013 for Win32 desktop development, you can also use the NuGet package manager to install Effects 11. See [fx11_desktop_2013](https://www.nuget.org/packages/fx11_desktop_2013/).